# Supplying method context when creating new safe transaction

Tags: gnosis-safe

Is there any way to supply methodName when creating a new safe transaction using safeSDK.txs.send, so that in *Transactions* tab the given methodName shows up instead of *Contract interaction*?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the contract is verified on etherscan/sourcify, then the method will pop up. The decoding of transaction data happens on the backend.